# Disable Charts.js animations in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, charts, polymer, chart.js

I'm using Polymer with Charts.js's port from [here](https://github.com/robdodson/chart-elements). I can't seem to figure out how to apply the normally available `options` in Charts.js. I want to disable the animations, so I do:

```
<chart-line data="[[data]]" options$=[[optionsData]]>lol</chart-line>
```

and in the Polymer constructor:

```
this.optionsData = "options:{animation:{duration: 0}}"
```

This is not working. How can I apply options?

Answer (score 0):

`<chart-line>.options` requires an `Object`, which means `optionsData` should be an `Object`. You've assigned a `string` to that property (and a malformed JSON string at that), but you should be assigning the actual JSON object like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.optionsData = {animation: {duration: 0}};
}
```

or more simply:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.optionsData = {animation: false};
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/aweGRJ?editors=1010)